# Jenkins - access archived artifacts from downstream job

Tags: jenkins

I'm a little confused on what exactly jenkins (2.74) is doing when archiving artifacts from a maven project. It appears from the logs that jenkins is automatically archiving artifacts in the project without having to specify a post-build action. The artifact files are indeed in the `jobs/<project>/modules` subdirectory and are available for download from the jenkins webui.

When triggering a follow-on job, I've added a build step to copy artifacts from the upstream (which build: upstream build that triggered this job) without specifying artifacts. The log files for the downstream state that is has copied artifacts from the upstream job. But I'm unable to see them in the workspace.

Are the artifacts available to the downstream job? If so, where are they?

Or do I need to explicitly archive the artifacts (with filenames) in the upstream job and explicitly copy the artifacts by filename in the downstream job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your downstream job, you should set this kind of configuration:
[image]

To specify the artifacts you want to retrieve from your upstream job and where you can to copy them.

In your case, we copy the openidm-zip file into a local "archives" folder.